# Partial Residual in OLS or Lasso case

Tags: regression, least-squares, lasso

I have a similar question as in this [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351552/correlation-between-the-j-feature-and-partial-residual).

Assume I've a regression
$y_i=\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\beta_3x_3+\epsilon_i$

And the partial residual is defined as:
$r_i^{(3)}=y_i-\left(\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2\right)$

Now we want to regress the partial residual on $x_3$:

$r_i^{(3)}=\beta_3^{res}x_3+\epsilon_i^{res}$

How could I interpretate a high positive and a high negative $\beta_3^{res}$ ?