# Can be λ in lasso exceed one?

Tags: lasso

let's consider the lasso problem as:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\|y-X\beta\|_2^2 + \lambda\|\beta\|_1 
$$
and referring to  [The lasso by Patrick Breheny](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjtwp_Zr5r8AhXO0qQKHQJnBU8QjBB6BAgUEAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmyweb.uiowa.edu%2Fpbreheny%2F7240%2Fs19%2Fnotes%2F2-13.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0AmYJ7lAnvQBNvTr15IfyA)
[image]

he says *the correlation between a predictor and residuals, must exceed a certain minimum threshold  λ before it is included in the model*.

what if we chose λ equals 2 or any value larger than 1. how that statement could be true? as we know the correlation (Pearson correlation) lies between -1,1. or let's say by that statement if the correlation between a predictor and residuals =0.99 and λ = 2 (arbitrary example) then none of the predictors of my model won't be included in the model

Comment: That's not a correlation, that's a covariance.   I wonder if he just experienced a brief mental lapse while typing in his slides?

Comment: I think it's a correlation, not a covariance as all variables are standardized.

Comment: @Nidal a residual is not standardized.

Comment: @AdamO "the variables that have equal (and maximal) absolute correlation with the residual"

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351552/correlation-between-the-j-feature-and-partial-residual read this also